# Where can I get latest Ethereum2 information?

Tags: casper

Somtimes Ethereum developers like Vitalik mention about Ethereum2. Where can I get latest information about Ethereum2 ideas or roadmap?

Comment: Roadmaps are moving targets and not a good fit for StackExchange. It's better to ask on another site like the [Ethereum reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum).

Answer (score 4):

You can find Ideas in this gitter-channel for research: https://gitter.im/ethereum/research

Comment: Is there any summary?

Comment: See also the Ethereum Foundation's public research forum https://ethresear.ch